# POST data from html attribute data-kay in JSON format inside AngularJS controller, after ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have issue with POST data from custom data-key attribute in buttons/div. 
App, after load GET value for data-key attribute. After clicking one, button make a function with POST value from this attribute.

Problem is that I have troubles with make correct $scope, to pass correct value in JSON format, from clicked button (app has 1-3 clickable buttons, each has different value ).

Please for hint or advice, best regards,

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'crm', [] );

myApp.controller( 'AppCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function ( $scope, $http ) {
  console.log( 'Hello from controller!' );

  $http.get( '/xxx/dictionary' ).success( function (response) {
    $scope.items = response;
    console.log( 'I got data I requested: \n' + response);
    $scope.proceed();

  } );

  $scope.proceed = function () {
    var selectedOption = $scope.selectedOption;

    console.log( 'Count fn() clicked' );
    $http.get( '/xxxx/xxxx' ).success( function ( response ) {
      if (response) {
        console.log( 'You are in context, good luck! ' + '\n CI: ' + response + '\n Selected val: ' + $scope.selectedOption );
        $http.get( '/xxx/offers/' + selectedOption ).success( function ( response ) {
          $scope.offers = response;
          console.log( 'Got offers data I requested:\n' + response );
        } );
      }
      else {
        console.log( 'Please pick up a context!' );
      }
    } )
  };

  $scope.sell = function() {

    console.log( 'Sell clicked!' );
    $http.post( '/response' )...?        <--- Here is Problem
  };
```

View:

```
<div class="offer" ng-model="offerBox">

              <div class="offer-box" ng-repeat="offer in offers.offerDtoList">
                  <div class="offer-box__headline">
                      <div class="offer-box__lp"><span class="number">{{ offer.spaceId }}.</span></div>
                      <div class="offer-box__title" ng-model="offerHeadline"><span>{{ offer.offerProduct }}</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="offer-box__content">
                      <div class="offer-box__description">
                          <p>{{ offer.offerDetails }}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="offer-box__buttons">
                          <div class="btn btn-success" data-key="{{ offer.statusId }}" ng-click="sell()" ng-model="sell">sprzedaj</div>
                          <div class="btn btn-info" data-key="{{ offer.statusId }}" ng-click="plan()">zaplanuj</div>
                          <div class="btn btn-danger" data-key="{{ offer.statusId }}" ng-click="drop()">odrzuć</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: change the signature of `$scope.sell` to `function(offer)` and pass the offer in the click, e.g. `ng-click="sell(offer)"`.  Then you can post the specific `offer`.

Comment: As @Claies said. Additionnally don't put something in $scope if you don't use it in the view and .success is deprecated https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: function( offer ) is ok and works well, thnak you =). Now I have in $http object req like in DOCS. But could you tell me how can I join extra value from parametr data-key?(I had changed value from {{ offer.statusId }} to another data in string ) e.g. my Object looks like: 
var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/xxxx/response',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        "offerId": 0,
        "offerStatusId": offer.statusId,
        "responseCode": "ZAPL"
      }
    };
I wannt join it to end of data.

Answer (score 0):

I made `function ( offer, id )` in controller, and in view I made `sell( offer, $event )`, And I take value in controller with:

```
var action = id.target.attributes.data.value;
```

Thank you for hints, especially for hint `sell( offer )`

Regards!